# Split function not working properly

Tags: java

I am trying to split the string using **Split** function in java

```
String empName="employee name | employee Email";
String[] empDetails=empName.split("|");
```

it gives me result as

```
empDetails[0]="e";
empDetails[1]="m";
empDetails[2]="p";
empDetails[3]="l";
empDetails[4]="o";
empDetails[5]="y";
empDetails[6]="e";
empDetails[7]="e";
.
.
.
```

but when i try following code

```
String empName="employee name - employee Email";
String[] empDetails=empName.split("-");
```

it gives me

```
 empDetails[0]="employee name ";
 empDetails[1]=" employee Email";
```

why java split function can not split the string seperated by "|"

Comment: Java or C# here? There is no `Split` in Java, only `split`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method accepts a `regex` and not a `String`.

Since `|`  is a meta character, and it's have a special meaning in regex.

It works when you escape that.

```
String[] empDetails=empName.split("\\|");
```

**Update:**

[Handling special characters in java:OFFICIAL DOCS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html).

As a side note:

In java method names starts with small letters.it should be `split()` not `Split()` ..not the capital and small `s`

Comment: yeah i got it but my question is why we have to use escape in case of "|" and not for "-"

Comment: Note, this is Java, not C#. Should be `split`, not `Split`

Comment: @user1363086 because "-" is not a special character outside `[]`

Answer (score 5):

> but my question is why we have to use escape in case of "|" and not for "-"

Because `"|"` is a regex meta-character.  It means "alternation"; e.g. `"A|B"` means match `"A"` or `"B"`.  If you have problems understanding Java regexes, the javadocs for `Pattern` describe the complete Java regex syntax.

So when you split on `"|"` (without the escaping!), you are specifying that the separator is "nothing or nothing", and that matches between each character of the target string.

(For the record, `"-"` is also a meta-character, but only in a `"[..]"` character group.  In other contexts it doesn't require escaping.)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `.split("\\|");` instead of `.split("|");`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String[] empDetails=empName.split("\\|");
```