# Which characters not accept in split method?

Tags: java, string

I have the following code:

```
String s = "100$ali$Rezaie" ;
String[] ar = s.split("$") ;
```

The folowing characters do not work in split:

```
.   $    ^
```

Are there any other characters that will not be accepted in `split()` method?

Comment: Maybe reading the Javadoc for String.split() would give you the answer.

Comment: Reason: [split-function-not-working-properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865674/split-function-not-working-properly/18865684#18865684)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Java `split` takes a Regex expression.

Read about regex meta characters [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). They are :

> the backslash \, the caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot .,
>   the vertical bar or pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk
>   or star *, the plus sign +, the opening parenthesis (, the closing
>   parenthesis ), and the opening square bracket [, the opening curly
>   brace {<sup>[1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)</sup>

For the most part you can escape these characters with a backslash. In Java you need to escape that backslash with a second backslash. So in order to escape the meta characters you need to use `\\`.

So in your example:

```
String[] ar = s.split("\\$") ;
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `split` is a regular expression, not a single character.  The page at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html lists all the characters which have a special meaning in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

As the docs say, `split` takes a regexp as argument. Characters such as `.`, `$` and `^` have special meaning in regexpes.

And it's not to say you *couldn't* use those characters to split strings. No, you can simply escape the characters in regexp to make them behave "ordinarily".

```
String[] ar = s.split("\\$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\$");
```

The \ is really equivalent to a single \ (the first \ is required as a Java escape sequence in string literals). It is then a special character in regular expressions which means "use the next character literally, don't interpret its special meaning".

Answer (score 0):

`split()` method accepts a regular expression as its input. Whatever RegEx has issues with, split() will have issues with that.
Here are the docs for Regex tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

The [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class lists the use of Regular Expression in Java. Any character that you find there has to be escaped if used in regular expression syntax.

If you want to treat that character as regular character you need to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use  "\"(double slash)  as a prefix and we can split the string..

```
String s = "100$ali$Rezaie" ;
String[] ar = s.split("\\$") ;
for (String str : ar) {
System.out.println(str);
}
```