# How to read tsv file from java and display in table format

Tags: java

I write the like reading tsv file with

```
datarow.splite("\t");
```

but if the tsv file contain `"\t"` it displaying `\t` means it is taking `\t` as normal text

```
public class Tsv_read{

public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

BufferedReader TSVFile = 
    new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.tsv"));

String dataRow = TSVFile.readLine(); // Read first line.

while (dataRow != null){
String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\t");
for (String item:dataArray) { 
  System.out.print(item + "  "); 
  }
System.out.println(); // Print the data line.
dataRow = TSVFile.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
}
// Close the file once all data has been read.
TSVFile.close();

// End the printout with a blank line.
System.out.println();

 } //main()
} // TSVRead
```

Comment: Try using `String[] dataArray = dataRow.split("\\t");`

Comment: You need to use **\\t** instead of **\t**

Comment: I answered the same here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18865684/1927832  Hope that helps.

Comment: no it's not working. I have tried.

Comment: If you're just trying to replace each tab character with two spaces, you could just use the `replace` method of the `String` class.  What you've done here is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 9):

Don't try to parse TSV by hand as there are a few corner cases such as escaping/unescaping, not to mention performance/memory issues with large files & lack of flexibility (especially converting values, choosing what columns to read and in what order, etc).

Try [uniVocity-parser's TSV parser](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial). Here's a simple example:

```
TsvParserSettings settings = new TsvParserSettings(); //you will find MANY options here

TsvParser parser = new TsvParser(settings);

// parses all rows in one go.
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(YOUR_INPUT_HERE);
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Answer (score 3):

Try this code I hope that helps you

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Tsv_read{

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

        StringTokenizer st ;
        BufferedReader TSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.tsv"));
        String dataRow = TSVFile.readLine(); // Read first line.

        while (dataRow != null){
            st = new StringTokenizer(dataRow,"\t");
            List<String>dataArray = new ArrayList<String>() ;
            while(st.hasMoreElements()){
                dataArray.add(st.nextElement().toString());
            }
            for (String item:dataArray) { 
                System.out.print(item + "  "); 
            }
            System.out.println(); // Print the data line.
            dataRow = TSVFile.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
        }
        // Close the file once all data has been read.
        TSVFile.close();

        // End the printout with a blank line.
        System.out.println();

    } //main()
} // TSVRead
```

Answer (score 0):

it is working with stringtokenizer

```
 while (dataRow != null){
        st = new StringTokenizer(dataRow,"\\t");
        while(st.hasMoreElements()){
            dataArray.add(st.nextElement().toString());
        }
```

Comment: -0.5. From the [Javadoc for StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) - "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."